# Enable/Disable re-actively a hyperlink in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

**Scenario :**

I have a Simple Hyperlink on Sidebar of a Dashboard.

```
<a href="/client/workspace">
    <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span>Workspace</span>
</a>
```

**Problem:**

The hyperlink must be click-enabled only when `CONDITION` is `true`, else it must be disabled.

Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance.

> **NOTE** : Using Meteor + blaze only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on having an  for the link, remove the href attribute and make it act like a button like this:

```
<a class="myLink" role="button" link="/client/workspace">
    <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span>Workspace</span>
</a>
```

Define its behavior like this:

```
Template.yourTemplate.events({
    '.myLink': function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       if (CONDITION) {
           // your code to redirect to event.target.link
       }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a `<button>` can really be `disabled` (simply set the `disabled` attribute value to the result of your condition).

An `<a>` link can always be clicked, so depending on what UI you exactly you want, we could imagine:

- Hiding the link behind a transparent (possibly with some opacity) `<div>`, so that it can no longer be clicked. The positioning of the `<div>` must be done carefully, while its presence / absence can be easily set (e.g. using a class that has `display: none` style).
- Listening to the `"click"` event on the link and preventing the default behaviour (i.e. `event.preventDefault()`, where `event` is the first argument of the listener) depending on the result of your condition.

Comment: that was lightening fast response.